# SQL dynamic WHERE clause DataSet

Tags: sql, dynamic

I have a SQL queries with a where clauses that have to exclude rows based on a list of values of some columns, these list may be hard coded (suplied by the users) or constructed from other select query.
Also the hard coded list may be updated by the users, so I need every time to update the list on the query, and that is inconvinient.

I am wondering about the best way to parameter these lists.

Exemple of WHERE clause :

```
WHERE
Article_Code not in ('PA_003','PA_003','PE_234','FR_980','FA_333','FC_001','TA_999','FC_212','DC_009','FF_333','PR_001')
AND
((Partner_Status != 'Radied') or (Partner_Status = 'Radied' and Partner_Code in ('PR_000453','PR_0004311T','PR_V3345','PR_004D55') )) 
AND
(Case_Code not in (select Case_Code from Agreement where DDR = 3))
```

One though is to build a table of parameter with this structure : (ExclusionCode - Column - ColumnMemberToExclude - ExclusionDescription) :

- ExclusionCode is an internal code that I gnerate to identify the reason of exclusion.
- Colum is the column to use on the where (ex: Article_Code)
- ColumnMemberToExclude is the member to use in the where (ex: PA_003)
- ExclusionDescription : functional description (ex: exclude the list of porsche product)

and then construct the where clause as a string from this table.

Is this the best way to do ?

Comment: 1) State the RDBMS (product and version) and tag your question with the appropriate. 2) What does *constructed from other select query* mean? Constructed as *comma-separated-list* or as a table/result-set/array/what ever...?

Comment: I mean I need to select the list of value to exclude from a table, like that : AND
(Case_Code not in (select Case_Code from Agreement where DDR = 3))

Comment: Sorry, this is absolutely unclear for me... Try to think with a foreigner's head. I do not even know which dialect of SQL you are using. You did not state, which part might be *dynamically created*, you did not tell, what `dynamically` means actually (statement creation on string level?)... Please edit your question and provide more details!

Comment: I would create a relation between users and their excluded codes, e.g. excluded_articles(user_id, article_code), so you can just say: where article_code not in (select article_code from excluded_codes where user_id = ...)

Comment: @maraca
Thx for your reply...the user may add a column (like article_code) and members to exclude from that column... so columns name should also be dynamic